# Having trouble concatenating quotes into my string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some code that creates a dynamic query. My one issue is getting double quotes in a particular spot, and currently I am stumped.

Here is my simple function that returns the query (this function has more to it, and the query returned is further used in more code, but that is irrelevant to the issue at hand, so I have shortened it for simplicity):

```
create or replace function pivotcode (tablename varchar, rowc varchar, colc varchar, 
 cellc varchar, celldatatype varchar) returns varchar language plpgsql as $$
declare
    dynsql1 varchar;
    dynsql2 varchar;
    columnlist varchar;
begin
    dynsql1 = 'select string_agg(distinct ''''||'||colc||'||'' '||celldatatype||''', '','' 
     order by ''''||'||colc||'||''  '||celldatatype||''') from '||tablename||';';
    return dynsql1;
end
$$
```

You can call the function like so:

```
select pivotcode('custuserfieldsvalues','userid','attributename','attributevalue','varchar');
```

It currently returns a query like this:

```
select string_agg(distinct ''||attributename||' varchar', ',' 
 order by ''||attributename||' varchar') from custuserfieldsvalues;
```

However, what I need it to return is like this:

```
select string_agg(distinct '"'||attributename||'" varchar', ',' 
 order by '"'||attributename||'" varchar') from custuserfieldsvalues;
```

The second one has double quotes around the *attributename* so that any text with spaces is properly quoted, once the final query is executed.

Can someone help with what changes I need to make to the ***_dynsql1 =*** line to get my desired result?

Comment: The code under "what I need" does not seem to make sense. Neither the quotes nor the type name. Nor does it make sense to add hard-coded double-quotes, that can't guarantee proper quotes. Seems like we are in the middle of a misguided solution to an undisclosed problem.

Answer (score 2):

Things like that are much better done using `format()`

```
dynsql1 := format('select string_agg(distinct %I, %I order by %I, %I) from %I', colc, celldatatype, colc, colldatatype, tablename);
```

The placeholder `%I` is for "identifiers" and will correctly quote them if needed.